# laravel addSelectRaw() - how to bind a variable in addSelect()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I addSelectRaw() in order to bind my variables to addSelect()?

I've got this in my code:

```
$query->addSelect( DB::raw('MATCH(matchy.val) against ("'.addslashes($q).'") as relevance ') );
```

addslashes() is far less than ideal, and i should be binding to a ? instead.  How can I do addSelectRaw() instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

selectRaw() behaves like addSelect already - selectRaw() actually adds the columns.

you can just do this:

```
$query->selectRaw('MATCH(matchy.val) against (?) as relevance ', [$q] );
```

(When I was searching for the answer to this question, I duckgo'ed 'laravel addselect' and couldn't find anything, so I decided to post this and answer my own question.)

Comment: @francisco - sorry for the confusion.  the part in parentheses is irrelevant.